# Why is CollapsingToolbarLayout putting a empty space under expanded content

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am trying to use `CollapsingToolbarLayout` but getting this blue space under my content. Collapsed state doesn't have this problem.

[image]

The Empty space under the expanded content seems to be equal to status bar height. I am unable to understand why that would happen.
My `xml` looks like this

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ...>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" ...>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                  app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
                  app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed|enterAlwaysCollapsed"
                  app:statusBarScrim="@android:color/transparent">

                 <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                      android:id="@+id/expanded_toolbar"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax".../>

             <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:elevation="6dp"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:navigationIcon="?attr/homeAsUpIndicator"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
                    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.../>
               </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

           </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
      </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Update**

I found a workaround for the time being

```
collapsingToolbar.post {
            val params = (collapsingToolbar.layoutParams as ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)
            params.height = findViewById<View>(R.id.expanded_toolbar).height
            collapsingToolbar.layoutParams = params
        }
```

Comment: Remove app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary" in CollapseToolbar and test it still remain or not

Comment: Doesn't help. It makes the collapsed state toolbar's background color transparent with expanded state content under it. @AliKhaki

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing the `layout_height` of your `collapsing toolbar` to `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent`

I believe that the blue color is because of the toolbar within the collapsing toolbar. So you should make sure that your background is applied to the appbar layout, or the collapsing toolbar layout.

However, that may cause problems since you're using an image background instead of just a color. So I recommend that you keep track of the collapsing toolbar's status, whether it's collapsed or open, and update your background accordingly.

Comment: This could be a good reference for what you're doing 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTYuLho5_rE

Answer (score 0):

Setting "match_parent" in the constraint inside the CollapsingToolbarLayout works for me:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                      android:id="@+id/expanded_toolbar"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                      app:layout_collapseMode="parallax".../>
```